# Regex to split a string up on each {space} but not when contained in quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am not very good with regex (in fact don't know much at all). I need to create an array from a string split at the spaces BUT only when the space isn't within double quotes so:

```
this.line "should be 3" elements
```

would appear like:

```
this.line
should be 3
elements
```

I know I can use preg_match to get the array but I have no clue on the regex.

p.s I have looked at other solutions in Stack Overflow but the regex doesn't seem to work with my preg_match.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
preg_match_all('/"[^"]+"|\S+/', $s, $matches);
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/5JIBQ)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Any chance of a break down as to what each segment does? I don't want to keep asking about regex :)

Comment: @webnoob He does not split, rather he matches, either something between " or everything which is not whitespace. Clever thing :) +1